# Android Gradle: How to access java class from module in build.gradle script file?

Tags: android, gradle, javassist

I want to develop a small android library and share it later with the community. I want to use [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), especially the project [morpheus](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/morpheus) to manipulate the bytecode of annotated classes during the build time.

Currently im stuck while i want to use my TestTransformer class from the Library within the TestApplications build.gradle script. The TestTransformer.java is defined as usual within the library project.

**library build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.stephanenicolas.javassist:javassist-build-plugin-api:1.0.0'
}
```

**application build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.stephanenicolas.morpheus:morpheus-plugin:1.0.8'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'morpheus'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    //compile 'com.github.stephanenicolas.morpheus:morpheus-plugin:1.0.8'
    compile project(':testlibrary')
}

morpheus {
    //transformers = new example.com.testlibrary.TestTransformer()
    transformers = new com.example.testlibrary.TestTransformer()
}
```

**TestTransformer.java**

```
import javassist.build.IClassTransformer;
import javassist.build.JavassistBuildException;

public class TestTransformer implements IClassTransformer {
    @Override
    public void applyTransformations(CtClass ctClass) throws JavassistBuildException {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldTransform(CtClass ctClass) throws JavassistBuildException {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now i get the following error when i try to sync the projects with gradle files:

```
Error:(44, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file     'C:\Users\MyUser\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApplication\app\build.gradle': 44: unable to resolve class com.example.testlibrary.TestTransformer 
 @ line 44, column 20.
 transformers = new com.example.testlibrary.TestTransformer()

1 error
```

Is it even possible to achieve my planned propose?

Thanks alot!

Comment: what do you want to say with your comment. i don't get it

Comment: sorry .. this one com.github.stephanenicolas.javassist:javassist-build-plugin-api:1.0.0  i don't think you can .. they are compiled classes..look for the open source in the internet

Comment: i don' think so. It must to do something with the classpath. This must be an configuration issue.